# How to access a application from public internet which is deployed in Websphere server 7.0 in IBM SMART Cloud?

Tags: websphere, cloud, maximo

I have installed a middleware component and websphere 7.0 was installed as part of this middleware installation. I have deployed Maximo 7.5 application ear (maximo.ear) in this websphere 7.0.

I am quite successful accessing this application in SMART cloud Instance.

I have disabled the Windows firewall setting as well. But still it is not working.

I don't know where to configure and what to configure to access this Maximo application from public internet which is deployed in websphere server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to open a port for access from outside your network. As I don't know enough of your setup here a some steps to help you on your way.

1. check which port is required to be open, default maximo is port 80 (most http servers are default port 80.
2. check if you have a public ip address (this is a requirement). If you don't have a public address you can use dns tools to forward traffic to you.
3. open the port on your router, this can be different on routers, but the key point is to open the port you found in step 1 (probably port 80)

**

### to check which port you need to open is simple:

**

if your address looks like `http://ipaddressornameofyourserver/maximo` then it's port 80.

if it's something like `http://ipaddressornameofyourserver:****/maximo` the `****` is your port.

### to check if you have a public ip

1. ask you isp
2. check your ip using [whatsmyip](http://whatsmyip.org) (see if it changes from time to time, if it changes you don't have a public IP, but this could take some time)
3. ask your IT personnel, if you're not from the IT department yourself and if you have an IT department.

### to open the port in your router

1. check with the it department (again if you are not the in the department yourself or if you are part of it)
2. consult your router guides

Usually you will find it under:

- port forwarding
- application ports
- firewall rules

### don't forget

Sometimes their are both a firewall (hardware or software) that could block traffic going to/from you server, please allow or disable that firewall too. Remember this is not the same firewall found on your server (the one you already disabled)